# SQL Server slow down issue, occupies more than allocated memory. Possible Leak

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Using SQL Server 2012 64 bit (v11.0.6020.0)

Below is the scenario:

On our production we have 32 GB DDR3 RAM installed:

[image]

Maximum memory limit has been set in SQL server to 16 GB ie 50% capacity:

[image]

When I fire up task manager and check memory occupied in Value it shows 16 GB which is correct:

[image]

But when I select memory occupied by Percentage, it shows 80%-85% which is NOT RIGHT:

[image]

This will keep on Increasing, until it occupies more than 95% and the

1. entire system will slow down
2. Queries will time out

The only way to correct this is a server restart

My questions are

1. Is SQL Server leaking memory?
2. Any quick fix so I don't have to restart?
3. Permanent resolution?

Comment: You'd better ask this question at https://dba.stackexchange.com .

Comment: If you have changed memory settings recently, you have to restart after changing these memory allocations

Comment: Things like this always bug me... 16,000MB and 16GB are **not** the same value (1,000MB != 1GB). 1,024MB = 1GB and 16,384MB = 16GB. 16,000MB = 15.625GB. On the subject of Task Manager, I woulnd't trust that to see how much RAM SQL Server is using. Try: `SELECT object_name, cntr_value AS Mem_in_KB, cntr_value / 1024 AS Mem_in_MB FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters WHERE counter_name = 'Total Server Memory (KB)';`

Comment: @BHouse No settings have been changed.

Comment: @Larnu I understand they are not exactly the same. But still 30% of RAM use is unaccounted for. I would have ignored the % utilization, but when it reaches 95% the system crashes.

Comment: @sunny have you checked if integration services or as/rs running in windows. Memory is accounted only for management studio

Comment: @BHouse Nope. SSIS is not running in windows.